# Error when we use Google-Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

Good day.

When we use Google Analytics on site wordpress, we get point on page:

[image]

Tell me plase why and how create this point and how delete her ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have CSS that automatically adds borders to all the images on your site.

You are using a No Javascript version of Google Analytics with an image (1x1) like this one:

```
<img src="http://nojsstats.appspot.com/UA-123456/your-website.com" height="1" width="1" >
```

You could try to adjust your CSS to remove the borders of this image.

For example you could target the relevant image source (not supported by all browsers):

```
img[src*="nojsstats.appspot.com"]{visibility:hidden;}
```